# OnSuccess of Ajax request check if array contains data

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, ajax

I have an Ajax request, when it gets to on success function I start to do things with `data.d.results` like reading through and filtering in another REST API.

However sometimes `data.d.results.ID` for example is undefined because the array returned is empty.

What condition can I use in my if loop to check if data actually contains any data, if it does I can run my code else I'll just skip this function?

I have seen indexof and contains but I was unsure if this would work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code in your success function:

```
if(data.d.results && data.d.results.length) {
    //Data found - write your code here
}
```

For Example:

```
if(data.d.results && data.d.results.length) {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
        console.log("Item ID: " + data.d.results[i].ID);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you! This is great, what does the && operator mean in this content?

Comment: && is a logical AND operator. It is used to check two conditions together if the results are not undefined AND the results has length (it means it has some items in it).

Comment: Also, Please [Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.